# php pdo binding multiple values issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code in php to query the database based on an array sent by the client.

```
$limit = $_POST['limit'];
$userArray = json_decode($_POST['arr'], true);
$queryPlaceholders= implode(',', array_fill(0,count($userArray), '?'));
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableA
                          WHERE tableA.id IN (".$queryPlaceholders.")
                          LIMIT ?");
foreach($userArray as $k => $val){
    $stmt->bindParam(($k+1), $val);
}
$stmt->bindValue(count($userArray) + 1, (int)trim($limit), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result;
```

This code appears to have an error. If I send an array containing the values 11 & 17, the query seems to only run with the value 17, not both 11 and 17.

If I `print_r($userArray)` I get `Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 17
)`

so I know php has the correct array. However, running this query with the code above, and running the query below yields different answers:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE tableA.id IN (11,17)
LIMIT 10
```

When running the code above, It appears to infact run this query?

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE tableA.id IN (17)
LIMIT 10
```

I've also placed statements in the `foreach` loop that tells me both elements of the array (11 & 17) are being bound to the $stmt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in the SQL statement that was use to prepare the statement. Unlike [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) is called.

Since `$val` is changed on each iteration of the `foreach` loop, it ultimately is the same for each placeholder when the query is finally executed.